# Trying to avoid nested SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I'm not sure even if nested `SqlConnections` are possible but I would really like to stay away from it. I've run into a scope issue now in my code and I'm trying to figure out how to get around it.

So until recently I had a global `SqlConnection` which is opened when the application starts and closed when it finished. I've now discovered the concept of .NET's connection pool so I've changed my code such that every `SqlCommand` (or group of them) uses its own, freshly created and opened, `SqlConnection`, trusting .NET to manage the pool and the accompanying overhead.

The problem I'm now having is that I have several blocks of code that look something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ClassGlobal.ConnectionString))
{       
    sqlConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("SQL code here", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand("SQL code here", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    ClassGlobal.WriteAction(action);
}
```

while the ClassGlobal.WriteAction() function looks something like this:

```
public static void WriteAction(MyActionClass action)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ClassGlobal.ConnectionString))
    {       
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Write the action to the DB", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, a new `SqlConnection` is created inside `WriteAction()` which is called from inside the scope of the first `SqlConnection`. Not good! I'm trying to avoid this.

In the past it wouldn't have been a problem seeing as there were none of these `using (SqlConnection)` blocks and all `SqlCommands` pointed to the same (global) `SqlConnection`. Obviously I could simply move my call to `WriteAction()` down below the closing curly brace of the `using (SqlCommand)` but:

1. The `action` instance that I pass to it is often instantiated and populated while inside the scope of the `SqlConnection` so I'd have to make more changes (lots of them) to move those out of the `SqlConnection` scope. There are loads of them and it will be hairy.
2. I'd actually prefer if the `WriteAction()` call could be inside the `SqlConnection` scope as in the example above so that I can wrap all of it in a `TransactionScope`, something that wasn't possible thus far but certainly seems like a good idea.

So here's what I plan on doing but I'd like to hear if any of you would consider this not to be good practice or whether you can suggest a better approach. (I've recently discovered that my global `SqlConnection` was not a good practice and it resulted in lots of time spent on fixing it. I'd like to avoid such a discovery in future).

How about I add a parameter to the `WriteAction()` function so that it looks as follows:

```
public static void WriteAction(MyActionClass action, SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{   
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Write the action to the DB", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This means that, rather than moving the calls to `WriteAction()` outside of the `SqlConnection` scope, I can simply add the `SqlConnection` as a parameter to the function so that the `SQLCommand` inside the function make use of the same connection, even if that connection is enlisted to a `TransactionScope`.

For the few instances where I call `WriteAction()` from outside the scope of any `SqlConnection`, I can write an overloaded function that looks like this:

```
public static void WriteAction(MyActionClass action)
{
    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ClassGlobal.ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            WriteAction(action, sqlConnection);
        }
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Does this look like a good idea or am I going to rue this decision in another two years?

Comment: looks fine to me. However, an overload to put a transaction around a single operation looks wrong. I'm guessing that was just illustrative.

Comment: Yes, of course. My WriteAction() function actually has many more than just a single SQL operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the `SqlConnection` instance to the method is absolutely fine. However, i'm not sure if you last approach, the overloaded method without the `SqlConnection` is a good idea. It hides the fact that you should better use the other, new overload. It makes the code compile which prevents you from fixing code which should be fixed now.

Note that the `using` block is not the problem but an opened connection. As long as you don't open the connection, the connection-pool does not need to open a physical connection.

So it is also a viable option to close the connection before you call  `WriteAction`:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ClassGlobal.ConnectionString))
{       
    sqlConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("SQL code here", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand("SQL code here", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    // ...
    sqlConnection.Close();

    ClassGlobal.WriteAction(action);

    // ... perhaps open it again here
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Whenever a user calls `Open` on a connection, the pooler looks for an
>   available connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available,
>   it returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When
>   the application calls `Close` on the connection, the pooler returns it
>   to the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once
>   the connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on
>   the next `Open` call.

So you can see that the nested `using` in `WriteAction` is not a problem so long as you don't keep the outer connection open. Don't confuse the connection instance with a physical connection.

Comment: Thanks. That is definitely very good advice. In fact, this is the first time I understand the purpose of SqlConnection.Close(). I've always wondered about that seeing as the closing curly brace does the same thing.

I often have more SqlCommands after the call to WriteAction() though. Would you prefer passing the connection or just calling sqlCommand.Open() again after the call to WriteAction()?

Comment: @DewaldSwanepoel: it's a matter of taste without more background informations. `ClassGlobal.WriteAction` sounds as if it can be called from everywhere. Then it's not nice to expect the the caller has a `SqlConnection`. A different question is if such global methods without context/class are best practices at all. That's against the principle of OOP. Another question is if you should not refactor the method of the outer using to do less things by creating new methods for each step or by providing one stored-procedure for all.